# No Clang warning for uninitialized field in struct

Tags: c, struct, clang

Consider the following struct:

```
typedef struct foo {
    int a;
    int b;
} foo;
```

My compiler issues no warning for the following statement:

```
foo m = {300};
```

Why is no warning emitted? I expected a warning, since I have not provided any value for the final field of the struct.

Here is my compiler invocation:

```
clang -Wall -Wpadded -Wuninitialized -g bar.c
```

Here is my clang/LLVM version:

```
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

Will the `b` field just contain garbage? Is this safe?

Comment: Formatting your code does not just make it more beautiful, but also increases the chance you see errors easier.

Comment: Could you give us a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Also, that's not gcc, that's clang (and it's a bit out of date).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-Wmissing-field-initializers` will warn you about missing field initializers in your struct initialization.

However, it looks like on clang that flag **won't** warn you if you choose to initialize a struct with no values.
For example

```
struct foo{
  int a;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  struct foo f = {};
  return 0;
}
```

Will emit no warnings even with `-Wmissing-field-initializers` on. If you'd like warnings in this case as well you should add the `-Wgnu-empty-initializer`.

### GCC

Although you asked about clang, this also works in GCC 
GCC will emit warnings for both cases when you pass in `-Wmissing-field-initializers`. There is no `-Wgnu-empty-initializer` flag for GCC.

Answer (score 9):

`-Wuninitialized` warns about uninitialised variables. But your *compound literal* very well **is** completely initialised.

C does not support *partial initialisation*. Fields in `struct`s and array initialisers or a compound literal which are not explicitly given are automatically set to `0`/`0.0`/null pointer (depending on type). So there is no need for the compiler to warn.

Maybe it is better practice in modern C to use designated initialisers, instead of the positional ones:

```
(move){orig_c, curr_c, ... }
```

Will store values to the first, second, etc. field, no matter which names it has and its type. This will cause trouble if you e.g. remove a field, but forget to remove the value:

```
// from field removed
(move){orig_c, curr_c, ... }
```

will set `to` and the following field. While this will generate an error for your `struct`, imagine the types were compatible.

Designated initialisers don't have this problem:

```
(move){ .from = orig_c, .to = curr_c, ... }
```

If you remove `from`, you will get an error about an unknown field name if you forget to change that list, too. Also you easier will see if you forgot a field. This is especially helpful for larger `struct`s.

---

Sidenote: Your compiler is **not** gcc, but llvm/clang. Apple unfortunately linked `gcc` to that compiler when they changed the toolchain for compatibility reasons. Bad idea, as the compilers are **not** fully compatible.

Comment: Your C-foo is hitting on all cylinders tonight, it takes a careful read to suss-out the partial initialization from the question `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Honestly, I'm really not sure what you mean and if that is critique or acknowledgement. Maybe it's just too late here or I just had a too hard week and my English skills are on holidays. I'd appreciate if you can clarify :-)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Ok, I think I know what you mean. Hope the edit is a bit better phrased now.

Comment: Yes, sorry for speaking in metaphors, that was intended to say good job. I missed the partial initialization hint in my first read of the question.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Actually I appreciate to learn new phrases. Keeps the brain working and (hopefully) enhances my own language skills. Only risk is I might ask for clarification. So, thanks for both :-)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer! However, it actually is possible to generate a warning for this: see Jason Teplitz's answer.

Comment: @dylhunn: Still, designated initialisers is the way to go! Also I'm not sure this works for a compound literal. This is not the same as an initialiser!

Answer (score 1):

`clang` will not warn you about uninitialized struct members at all, boolean or otherwise, even with `-Weverything`. Here's a demonstration.

```
$ cc --version
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0
Thread model: posix

$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct {
    int num1;
    bool flipped_moved;
    int num2;
} Thing;

void do_something(Thing *thing) {
    printf("%d %d %d\n", thing->num1, thing->num2, thing->flipped_moved);
}

int main ()
{
    Thing what;

    do_something(&what);

    return 0;
}

$ CFLAGS=-Weverything make
cc -Weverything -Wall -g    test.c   -o test
test.c:10:6: warning: no previous prototype for function 'do_something' [-Wmissing-prototypes]
void do_something(Thing *thing) {
     ^
test.c:7:9: warning: padding struct 'Thing' with 3 bytes to align 'num2' [-Wpadded]
    int num2;
        ^
2 warnings generated.

$ ./test
1431815496 1771089974 1
```

If, instead, `what` is partially initialized with `Thing what = {23};` then the rest of the fields are zero'd.

```
$ ./test
23 0 0
```